# Get Outlook Shared Calendar without Delegation VBA/C#

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, outlook-redemption

As the GetSharedDefaultFolder [method description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) states:

> This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder).

Is there a way to get shared calendar appointment items without being a delegate of the person?

For example, I could do an File -> Open -> Open User's Folder to see people's busy/free status for about anyone or mail box. But apparently this permission level won't enable the GetSharedDefaultFolder() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Recipient.GetFreeBusy` or `AddressEntry.FreeBusy` in this scenario.